# Checking that a decimal number is in a range in bc

Tags: shell-script, bc, floating-point, math

I've written this if, that is obviously not working, and I still can't manage to get over it:

```
#LASTEFFECTIVEHASH
if (( $(echo "$LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMINVAL < $LASTEFFECTIVEHASH < $LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMAXVAL" | $BC -l) )); then
                echo "$DATESTAMP - LASTEFFECTIVEHASH=$LASTEFFECTIVEHASH is between $LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMINVAL and $LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMAXVAL"|tee -a $LOGFILE
else
                echo "$DATESTAMP - LASTEFFECTIVEHASH=$LASTEFFECTIVEHASH is not between $LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMINVAL and $LASTEFFECTIVEHASHMAXVAL"|tee -a $MSGFILE $LOGFILE
fi
```

But, when value are out of ranges, it results in this:

```
20170810003646 - LASTEFFECTIVEHASH=139.2 is between 104.9 and 136.9
```

I'm following the maths syntax: if x > 104.9 and < 136.9, in maths you write it `104.9 < x < 136.9`. But I suspect that bash/bc are behaving differently from my math's teacher.

It would be great if bc won't fail to count up to 137 ;)

Comment: @John1024 Oh, I see, sorry. I got carried away with the title but the question is indeed about a different topic.

Comment: @Gilles thank you for reconsidering your decision. I did some research about this kind of issue before writing the post and I didn't find anything compatible to my case. Probably I didn't used right keywords, as I see you completely rewrote the question's title. Thanks a lot for your contribution indeed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike for example python, `bc` does not support chained comparisons:

```
a < b < c
```

To perform both comparisons and require both to be true, use logical-and (requires GNU bc):

```
(a < b) && (b < c)
```

For example:

```
$ a=104.9; b=136; c=136.9; if echo "($a < $b) && ($b < $c)" | bc -l | grep -q 1; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
$ a=104.9; b=137; c=136.9; if echo "($a < $b) && ($b < $c)" | bc -l | grep -q 1; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False
```

#### POSIX bc

If you don't have GNU bc, you can replace logical-and with multiplication:

```
$ a=104.9; b=136; c=136.9; if echo "($a < $b)*($b < $c)" | bc -l | grep -q 1; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
$ a=104.9; b=137; c=136.9; if echo "($a < $b)*($b < $c)" | bc -l | grep -q 1; then echo True; else echo False; fi
False
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly for my needs, your oneliner is now part of my script! ;)